# Confusion : In a class there are 30 students. Is it possible that, 9 of them have 3 friends (in the class), 11 - have 4, and 10 - have 5 friends?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Question : In a class there are 30 students. Is it possible that, 9 of them have 3 friends (in the class), 11 - have 4, and 10 - have 5 friends?

Solution : Let there be 30 vertices in the graph, 9 of which have degree 3, 11 - have degree 4, 10 - have degree 5. Meanwhile, in the graph, there are 19 odd vertices, which is against the "Handshake-Theorem", so it's not possible.

I didn't understand where is the statement "Meanwhile, in the graph, there are 19 odd vertices" from and by what do we get that information? I'm confused, please help me.

Comment: every student is a vertex, an edge represents friendship. So if a student has $n$ friends, the corresponding vertex has degree $n$. The statement that there are 19 odd vertices comes from just adding up all degrees of vertices of odd degree. Then apply the handshake theorem

Comment: I didn't understand, what do you mean by " there are 19 odd vertices comes from just adding up all degrees of vertices of odd degree", how it comes? @ Lassadar

Comment: "there is 30 vertices, 9 of them has degree 3, 11 - has degree 4, 10 - has degree 5"
to get the sum of vertices of odd degree sum up 9 + 10. Because 9 have degree 3 and 10 have degree 5 (both odd). The rest have degree 4 (even).

Comment: Understood, thank you very much. @Lassadar

Answer (score 4):

You can represent the problem using a graph of 30 vertices, where every vertex represents a different student and each edge between two vertices means they are friends. Since there are $9$ vertices with $3$ edges and $10$ with $5$ edges, and the rest of vertices has an even number of edges, we conclude we have exactly $19$ vertices with odd number of edges.

Now, the [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) states that **the sum of degrees of the vertices of a graph is twice the number of edges** (to be said, the number of vertices with odd degree is even). Notice this lemma applies for **finite undirected graphs**, which is our case since we hace just 30 vertices and it's undirected because if $A$ is friend of $B$, then we assume $B$ is also friend of $A$.

But the sum of the degrees of the vertices in our problem is odd, because it's the sum of $19$ odd numbers (obviously odd) plus $21$ even numbers (leaving the result odd). Since it's odd, it can't be twice a natural number, so we conclude this situation is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach.

Graph theory is not needed.

Every time that person $A$ is friends with person $B$, then you have that person $B$ is friends with person $A$.  Therefore, each distinct friendship results in $(2)$ "man-friends".

The idea is that if you have $n$ people, labeled #1, #2, ..., #n, and if you let $f(k)$ denote the number of friends that person #k has, among the $(n-1)$ other people, then you **must have that**

$$\left[\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)\right] ~\text{is an even number}.$$

If you review the statement of the question, the hypothetical $\left[\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)\right]$ would be an odd number, which is not possible.